# How to create a small view in IB for modal presentation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I am trying to create a small popup view in IB for modal presentation on the iPhone and the view height and width is grayed out and set to 320x480 in IB. Is there a way to do this? I've tried various settings but I've had no luck so far.

My plan is to display using:

```
[self presentModalViewController:systemViewController animated:YES];
```

Actually that is working now but the view is "fullscreen" and I want the modal view on top with the other view showing beneath as a background view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self presentModalViewController:systemViewController animated:YES];
```

This will always produce a full screen modal on iPhone, that's how the OS handles modals for that platform. Only on iPad are you able to change the presentation style to be page sheet, form sheet, or full screen.

You will need to implement something custom to achieve what you're after. This article is very  in depth on creating a custom alert view for iPhone, which I believe you'd be able to adapt for your needs:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

**P.S**: The method of modal invokation you've provided is now depricated, in future, if you need to produce normal modal view controllers, please use:

```
[self presentViewController:systemViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a really helpful insight. Actually, I can live with a full screen modal page on the iPhone. The addition of the modal view is a step towards adapting my iPhone App for iPad. Having said that, when I create the xib for the iPad, will IB allow me to change the size? I am aiming for a universal App, how will IB know this view is used on the iPad and not on the iPhone?

Comment: IB will allow you to set any size, but make sure you set your autoresize rules correctly incase the frame changes size. Your app can select the correct xib through various means. If the xib has the same name as it's iPhone counterpart, suffix the name with `~ipad`, as in `name~ipad.xib`, and your app will work as before. If it has a different name, then when loading the xib for your view controller, manually load it in code using it's name, using the conditional check of `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` to make sure you know which one to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the view's background transparent, and add a smaller view on top with the actual contents you want to display.  This will allow you to display it as a modal view while still showing the previous view underneath, but will not allow interaction with the previous view.

It worked for me, but no guarantees that this is a good idea.